# Need help installing the VUE plug in for TestCafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am new to the product and have minimal coding knowledge.  I need to install the testcafe-vue-selectors plugin but the instructions on the github page are lacking detail.  The say Install "$ npm install testcafe-vue-selectors"  Where do I run this command?

Thanks and sorry for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: run the command in cmd.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have already installed TestCafe by running a single command in your terminal (command-prompt):

`npm install -g testcafe`

To install the plug-in, you need to execute a similar command in your terminal (in your project folder):

`npm install testcafe-vue-selectors`

No additional steps are required. Just ensure that [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) and [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) are installed on your computer.